# Product layout bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently developing a drone site for my dad. I just started using bootstrap and its been a lot of fun! But I do keep running into small problems.

I used this [Website](http://www.layoutit.com/build) to generate a layout which looks like this:

[image: Layout Builder example]

I am trying to display a carousel to put the product pictures in with next to it some specs or description. But I just can't seem to get the pictures to fit as you can see here(or preview it [here](http://www.drones-center.nl/drone-pagina.php)):

[image: Website preview]

The code that I use including the carousel, tab buttons and ordered list if more code is needed please ask:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/Parrot-BeBop-Drone-14-MP-Full-HD-1080p-Fisheye-Camera-Quadcopter-Blue-0-3-300x300.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/parrot_bebop_skycontroller_yellow_img1-500x500-300x300.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>
                h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </h3>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </li>
                <li>
                    Consectetur adipiscing elit
                </li>
                <li>
                    Integer molestie lorem at massa
                </li>
                <li>
                    Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet
                </li>
                <li>
                    Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
                </li>
                <li>
                    Faucibus porta lacus fringilla vel
                </li>
                <li>
                    Aenean sit amet erat nunc
                </li>
                <li>
                    Eget porttitor lorem
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-628527">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#panel-433983" data-toggle="tab">Beschrijving</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#panel-884437" data-toggle="tab">Specificaties</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-433983">
                        <p>
                            I'm in Section 1.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-884437">
                        <p>
                            Howdy, I'm in Section 2.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could help me out fix my layout that would be great!

Comment: It seems like your index page has the carousel working perfectly? - http://www.drones-center.nl/index.php Try checking the code on that page and maybe try and use the same in our drone-pagina.php?

Comment: @devpod I might not have explained it properly but i dont want it the full with i want it small with the orderlist next to it.

Comment: Put them both on the same <div class="row"></div> and then create 2 columns, one for each element.

Comment: @devpod can you copy my code and put the awnser as an actual awnser? i dont really seem to understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by giving both of them on 1 row, and then divided it so that the space total sum is 12.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/Parrot-BeBop-Drone-14-MP-Full-HD-1080p-Fisheye-Camera-Quadcopter-Blue-0-3-300x300.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/parrot_bebop_skycontroller_yellow_img1-500x500-300x300.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>
                h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </h3>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </li>
                <li>
                    Consectetur adipiscing elit
                </li>
                <li>
                    Integer molestie lorem at massa
                </li>
                <li>
                    Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet
                </li>
                <li>
                    Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
                </li>
                <li>
                    Faucibus porta lacus fringilla vel
                </li>
                <li>
                    Aenean sit amet erat nunc
                </li>
                <li>
                    Eget porttitor lorem
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Simplified version

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
             //courosal
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            //Spek
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I add a container to them and put both of them into one row. But why 6 and 4? aren't the sum is 10?

Well, there is some problem with your CSS. It gives a weird space on the left.

[image: weird]

But hope it helps you understand the power of bootstrap.

Comment: Thx for the help, it worked feel free to check it out, im still editing it, if you have tips feel free to tell me that aswell!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You'll get **image** in **center** of the **container**. 
Otherwise you have to use **large images** to fit your container.